# Issue with getting the content_type of an image when other fields are also present in the form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model form:

```
class ImageModelForm(FilesForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image', 'order_id']


class FilesForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super().save(commit=False)

        for field, value in self.fields.items():
            if isinstance(value, forms.FileField) and obj:
                    obj.filename = truncate_filename(self.cleaned_data[field].name.lower())
                    obj.file_type = self.cleaned_data[field].content_type.lower()
        # commit is False usually in Admin - check to work also in Admin
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj

class Image(FileAttributesModel):

    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_upload_to, max_length=500)
    order_id = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

class FileAttributesModel(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

If I remove 'order_id' from form *or do not change* its value,  its working, otherwise I get:

```
 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'content_type'
```

In traceback the error is tracked on he save method:

```
obj.file_type = self.cleaned_data[field].content_type.lower()
```

In both cases the field is: image

but,With no value change to order_id

```
{'file': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000000005F7CE08>, '_name': 'broad-range.png', 'size': 76310, 'content_type': 'image/png', 'charset': None, 'content_type_extra': {}, 'field_name': 'image-1-image', 'image': <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=1000x468 at 0x64B8A20>}
```

with order_id changed:

```
{'_file': None, 'name': /images/broad-range.png', 'instance': <Image: images/06_axft.jpg>, 'field': <django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField: image>, 'storage': <django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage object at 0x00000000038FEDD8>, '_committed': True}
```

Comment: Can you post your model and traceback of error?

Comment: @Sanip I added more info

Comment: What is the extension of the file being saved? Can you have a look at it by printing the `cleaned_data[field].name`?

Comment: jpeg, but it doesn't matter, does the same with all images, but what is strange is if I remove the field order_id from the form or let the field default value it works

Comment: Check if the returned content is actually an image and not a string